# Template CMS system for user space within a site

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

Any ideas on a CMS system where I want to give each user a specific page to do their content and not be able to impact other users pages.  It seems most CMS system give a basic level of membership that doesnt allow this kind of setup.

Comment: When a question is migrated does it automatically migrate the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with [Drupal](http://drupal.org), but it's non-trivial -- the sort of thing you probably want to hire an experienced Drupal dev for if it is new to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have already suggested the following CMS to a couple of people already and I believe it could be handy for you: [SilverStripe CMS](http://www.silverstripe.org/).

If you check out the [demo](http://demo.silverstripe.org/) you'll notice that you can easily manage users and theirs permissions in the Security page (accessible from the top menu once logged in).